# JNI application hanging

Tags: java, c++, c, hadoop, java-native-interface

Please help how would you approach debugging a JNI application.

Used jps to get pid of the process that's running jvm:

```
$ jps
8248                <- this is the pid of the process that was span up by a C++ application to run JNI stuff ... 
8335 Jps
```

Now we can attach gdb to this stack.

```
$ gdb -p 8248
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-94.el7
....  /cut/   
(gdb)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fddd9f141bd in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fddd9f0fd02 in _L_lock_791 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007fddd9f0fc08 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fddda9f3e26 in mutexLock () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
#4  0x00007fddda9ed6f1 in setTLSExceptionStrings () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
#5  0x00007fddda9ec38c in printExceptionAndFreeV () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
#6  0x00007fddda9ec52d in printExceptionAndFree () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
#7  0x00007fddda9ed46b in getJNIEnv () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
#8  0x00007fddda9eee94 in hdfsBuilderConnect () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
#9  0x0000000000400950 in main ()
```

Notice that it's hanging in some sort of global mutex lock

I think this gdb backtrace stack should be very useful to identify the root cause of this issue.

This should be a generic JNI debugging question? If if you're interested here's C code that spans up a JVM for JNi interaction - https://gist.github.com/Tagar/7c42f82f5538004bda2f4ea0b0e0adc5

java version "1.8.0_141"
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC)

Runtime environment:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CDH/lib64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/$OS_ARCH/server
export CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath` 
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xss1280m
```

Thanks for any leads.

Also, based on the hanging stack it was trying to fail

```
#6  0x00007fddda9ec52d in printExceptionAndFree () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
#7  0x00007fddda9ed46b in getJNIEnv () from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/libhdfs.so.0.0.0
```

but hangs on attempt to 
printExceptionAndFreeV ()  -> setTLSExceptionStrings () -> mutexLock ()  lock..

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Edit rejected. JNI code is written in C or C++. OP hasn't specifeid which, and it isn't clear from the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause was found to be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-11851

Thanks.